# 16.04: Gnome shell with Dash to panel extension - System crashes when close app in hover preview

Tags: 16.04, gnome-shell

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, install gnome shell and [Dash To Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/) extension.

Every time I click to the close button in hover preview taskbar, the system UI crash and I must to logout and re-login.

How can I fix this problem? This is close button I clicked:

[image]

Comment: FYI: Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS is EOL; being a flavor it only had 3 years of supported life, so I'd suggest you run `ubuntu-support-status` to confirm your unsupported packages (ie. gnome) and consider if you want or should upgrade (Ubuntu server has 5 years, as does Ubuntu desktop with Unity, or Kylin desktop - all other 16.04 flavors are now EOL; http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/).

Comment: I must to use ubuntu 16.04 to run my system, I can not run in ubuntu 18.04 or newer.

Comment: Has this started happening after upgrading the extension? If so, try downgrading the extension.

Comment: @pomsky, I install lastest version. Which version you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not unlikely, more recent versions of Dash To Panel do not anymore work well with the older version of Gnome Shell that comes with Ubuntu 16.04. So if you must continue to use Ubuntu 16.04, uninstall your current extension, and then install the version that belongs to your version of Gnome Shell (see the dropdown menu "Shell version" next to the Download button). In Settings - About, you can see the version number of your Gnome Shell (the number next to "GNOME:")

Better yet, uninstall the extension and install it back using Synaptic package manager or the `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extension-dash-to-panel` command. That way, compatibility between your version of Gnome Shell and the extension is guaranteed (provided, though, that U 16.04 already has the APT package for the extension).

Answer (score 0):

Thank for all support. I tried to downgrade this extension then it work. Below version work for me:
[image]

Installation guide in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdqzxqDo7Sk)